# SELECT query with multiple results and condition on same column

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM `productattributes`
WHERE (value='Yes') AND (value='Hipster') AND (value='Half') AND (value='XS')
```

I want those result after matching all condition at the same time

[image: table screenshot]

Comment: so you need where IN()?

Comment: **OR** remember a column cannot be all those things a one time and the test is being applied to ONE column value at a time

Comment: On a sidenote: You certainly want `value='Yes'` for a particular `attr_id`. It makes a big difference whether 'Yes'  aplies to 'Can be tumble dried' or 'Can be washed' :-) With a key value table never look at a value without also looking at the key.

Comment: Please always tag your DBMS when asking SQL questions. Is it MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ... (Of course we can guess that this is MySQL, but we can be wrong and may give incorrect answers then.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM `productattributes`
WHERE value in ('Yes', 'Hipster', 'Half', 'XS')
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 4;
```

If you know that the values are not duplicated, you can use `COUNT(*) = 4` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  (The `DISTINCT` adds overhead.)

Comment: if i want  another conditions like attr_id='12' and attr_id='13' and attr_id='14' and attr_id='15'  at the same time then what i do?

Comment: Because i want those product in which these all attribute exist

Comment: @SharadYadav . . . Then you would have a different question.  You should ask new questions as a *question* not as a *comment*.  But, I'm think you just want `where ( (attr_id = 12 and value = 'Yes') or (attr_id = '13' and value = 'Hipster') or . . . )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `productattributes` WHERE value IN ('Yes', 'Hipster', 'Half', 'XS')
```

[More about SQL IN Operator.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to compare multiple values with a single column then either you have to use 'OR' condition instead of 'AND' or you can  use 'IN' method to compare data

```
SELECT *
FROM `productattributes`
WHERE (value='Yes') OR (value='Hipster') OR (value='Half') OR (value='XS')
```

Second Way using IN method

```
SELECT * FROM `productattributes` WHERE value IN ('Yes', 'Hipster', 'Half', 'XS')
```

Answer (score 0):

A `WHERE` clause looks at one row at a time. The content of the column `value` of a particular row can either be 'Yes' or 'Hipster' or 'Half' or 'XS'. Not all of these at the same time.

What you are probably looking for is either products matching at least one of the attributes or products matching all attributes.

**Products matching at least one attribute**

```
select distinct product_id
from productattributes
where (attr_id = 27 and value = 'Yes')
   or (attr_id = 25 and value = 'Half')
   or (attr_id = 32 and value = 'Hipster')
   or (attr_id = 28 and value = 'XS')
```

Here we merely look at a record if it matches one condition (e.g. value 'Hipster' for attribute ID 25). If so we select it's product ID. At last we use `DISTINCT` to get each product ID only once.

**Products matching all attributes**

```
select product_id
from productattributes
group by product_id
having sum(attr_id = 27 and value = 'Yes') > 0
   and sum(attr_id = 25 and value = 'Half') > 0
   and sum(attr_id = 32 and value = 'Hipster') > 0
   and sum(attr_id = 28 and value = 'XS') > 0
```

Here we don't look at single records. We count condition matches per product ID (an aggregation with `GROUP BY`). This solution makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0. So the sum is the count of matched conditions.

Comment: For Products matching all attributes for attribute length i have range like 45-50 then how to make above query  select product_id
from productattributes
group by product_id
having sum(attr_id = 27 and value = 'Yes') > 0
   and sum(attr_id = 25 and value = 'Half') > 0
   and sum(attr_id = 32 and value = 'Hipster') > 0
   and sum(attr_id = 28 and value = 'XS') > 0  and sum(attr_id = 29 and value = 'between 45 to 50') > 0

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this question.

Comment: i mean i am searching the product on the basis of attribute , I have one attribute length like above attribute .So for length i have a range 45-47 in the value field length is given then how to match the record  having length attr_id=29 and value between 45 to 50 also having above condition

Comment: Ah, it's about an attribute called "length". Okay. Well, what you store is a string '45-47'. The DBMS doesn't know about the meaning of the string content; for the DBMS it's just some string. You, however, know what to expect from the content, because of the attribute. So you can use string functions to get the lower number and the higher number. With numbers you can make comparisions, e.g. 45>=45 and 47<=50. (You can also store min length and max length as separate attributes to make this easier of course.)

Comment: Sorry,by mistake above comment is wrong,I mean i am storing length only a number like 46 .but when i search using length attr value my serch value is 45-50 means those product whose length attr is between 45 to 50 .the result is 46 .

Comment: Still you have a string where you want two numbers. So use string manipulation to extract them. If you don't know how, look up "string functions" in the docs or look for "extracting numbers from strings in MySQL". This is a new question, but one that has been answered multiple times.